# Showing/hiding a SWT Menu at runtime

Tags: java, swt, jface

I'm trying to dynamically show/hide (or create/dispose) a SWT Menu (via JFace MenuManager) at runtime, based on a simple event. More specifically, when a desired control is activated, I would like to show an additional menu in the menu bar. As soon as it's deactivated, the newly added menu should disappear. Something like this:

```
addListener(SWT.Activate, new Listener(){
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        showAdditionalMenuManager();
    }
});

addListener(SWT.Deactivate, new Listener(){
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        hideAdditionalMenuManager();
    }
});
```

The listeners definitely work, but I've tried both setVisible(), and disposing/recreating the menu (disposing gives results, recreating doesn't) with no luck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you're developing an RCP based application consider using a visibleWhen expression on the declaration of the sub-menu.

Comment: Can you give some additional information with the content of the two show/hide methods?

Comment: @TonnyMadsen It's not an RCP based app. The methods are as simple as e.g. additionalMenuManager.setVisible(false) or additionalMenuManager. dispose(). By the way, the setVisible() method does work, but only at launch time (when constructing the shell).

Comment: Hmm, I suspect that the parent menu manager is not properly updated... there are no automatics here... You must call `parent.updateAll(true)` on the parent as well. And possibly `parent.remove(additionalMenuManager)` first.

Comment: @TonnyMadsen That's brilliant! parent.updateAll(true) did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I suspect that the parent menu manager is not properly updated... there are no automatics here... You must call `parent.updateAll(true)` on the parent as well. And possibly `parent.remove(additionalMenuManager)` first.